# How Can I do a screen transition with a different direction in kivy python?

Tags: python, transition, kivy

I'm doing a kivy app with different `Screen` and I want to do the transition in the different screens to the right or to the left (it depends it is the first or the second screen). If somebody knows how to do the transition it would be helpful for me, I attach the code of my app here.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.properties import DictProperty,ListProperty

Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    MainScreen:
        name: 'main'
    SecondScreen:
        name: 'second'


<MainScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: "Select Subjects (1/2)"
            font_size: 15
        Label:
            text: " "
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240031',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Electromagnetisme"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240033',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Materials"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240052',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Termodinàmica"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240053',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Electrotècnia"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240054',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Mecànica dels Medis Continus"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240061',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Mecànica de Fluids"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240063',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Resistència de Materials"

        Button:
            text: "Exit"
            background_color: .7, 1, 6, 1
            on_release:root.parent.current='second'
        Button:
            text: "Next"
            font_size: 
            background_color: .7, .7, 1, 1
            on_release: root.parent.current='second'
<SecondScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Label:
            text: "Select Subjects (2/2)"
            font_size: 15
        Label:
            text: " "
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240072',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Electrònica"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240073',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Sistemes de Fabricació"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240151',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Tecnologia i Selecció de Materials"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240161',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Màquines Elèctriques"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240171',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Termotècnia"
        CheckBox:
            on_active:root.ping('240172',self.active)
        Label:
            text: "Control Automàtic"
        Label:
            text: ""
        Label:
            text: ""
        Button:
            text: "Previous"
            background_color: .7, 1, 6, 1
            on_release:root.parent.current='main'
        Button:
            text: "exit"
            background_color: .7, .7, 1, 1
            on_release: root.parent.current='main'

''')


class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(MainScreen, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.a = App.get_running_app()
        self.e={}
    def ping(self, n, value):
        self.a.big_dict[n] = value

class SecondScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(SecondScreen, self).__init__(**kw)
        self.a = App.get_running_app()
        self.e={}
        def ping(self, n, value):
            self.a.big_dict[n] = value
        def exit(self):
            return exit


class Root(ScreenManager):
    pass
class SimpleKivy(App):
    big_dict = DictProperty({'240161': False, '240061': False, '240171': False, '240151': False, '240063': False, '240073': False, '240072': False, '240031': False, '240033': False, '240054': False, '240053': False, '240052': False, '240172': False})
    def build(self):
        return Root()
SimpleKivy().run()
```

Comment: It seems like you only change screens in `kv` code. This case is [covered almost literally in the docs](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.screenmanager.html#changing-direction)

Comment: Adding `root.manager.transition.direction = 'left'` in a button doesn't work. I have tried with the `button`previous and still goes to the right when it gets pressed.

Comment: That's because the screen manager is accessed as `root.parent` in your code. Just like the existing handlers

Comment: Okay I was using the wrong direction. If I want to exit through a button in `kv` language how can I do it? `root.parent.current=exit` doesn't work. Thank you

Comment: Please work yourself through tutorials, docs, and examples. It doesn't seem like you know what you're doing...